# Broadleaf Demosite on JBOSS 7

Tags: spring, hibernate, jboss, e-commerce, broadleaf-commerce

I am trying to deploy the Broadleaf demosite application on JBOSS 7 server. I have followed
[Broadleaf Demo on JBOSS server topics](http://forum.broadleafcommerce.org/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=2496)
But still I am facing the following issue.

> **Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webDS': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: datasources/BroadleafDS -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.BroadleafDS**

Kindly help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application must be have JNDI resources.

You must be configure JNDI data sources in either standalone.xml or domain.xml

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasrc/ExaMYSQLDB" pool-
name="TestMYSQL" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
<connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/broadleaf</connection-url>
<driver>mysql</driver>
<security>
<user-name>root</user-name>
<password>root</password>
</security>
</datasource
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have corrected the datasource decleration. It works for me.